# Why the router is only matching one route in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, routes, router

I'm developing a client for a rest API using Angular 5 and a lazy loading architecture. I have the following routes in the `AppModule` that are imported using the `RouterModule` `forRoot()` method:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: 'app/register/register.module#RegisterModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot-password',
    loadChildren: 'app/forgot-password/forgot-password.module#ForgotPasswordModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'events',
    loadChildren: 'app/events/events.module#EventsModule',
  }
];
```

And then for `HomeModule`, `LoginModule`, `RegisterModule` and `PasswordModule` I only have this route for each one:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ...
  }
];
```

Each of them is imported using the `RouterModule` `forChild()` method. And for the `EventsModule` the routes are these:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EventSearchResultsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: NewEventComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: EventDetailsComponent
  }
];
```

The problem I'm facing is that every route in my application is loading the `EventDetailsComponent` except for the root route, that is loading correctly the `HomeComponent`. But if I delete the `:id` route from the `EventsModule` all is working fine! Why it stops working when I add the last route?

PS: To navigate to each of these routes I'm only using the routerLink directive like this `routerLink="/register">`.

Comment: Try changing path:’:id’ to something like path:’e/:id’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate, you should use

```
[routerLink]="['/register']" // absolute routing
[routerLink]="['register']" // relative routing
```

This will ease your navigation when you have to handle parameters.

Next, you should remove those lines

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule',
  },
```

Because what's the point of lazily loading a route than will be loaded by default ?

After that, you should define your routes, instead of using

```
{
  path: '', component: [Home|Register|Login|Password]Component
}
```

<s>Because all of those routes are equal : **defining the lazy loading strategy doesn't actually define routes**. The routes in the lazy loading strategy have to match the existing routes, and you have no routes set to `[register|home|login|password`.</s>  **EDIT** this isn't true

After that, you should not habe the problem (I think), and if so, please let me know what is the new problem so thzt I can help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the detailed answer! You are right, It does not make sense to lazy load the root route. I've only changed the root route to be eager loading instead of lazy and magically it's all working as expected... But I don't understand these line `defining the lazy loading strategy doesn't actually define routes.`  The lazy loading routes defined in the AppModule are matching with `register|home|login|password` and then in each of those modules the router matches the `''` route right?

Comment: When you define your LL strategy, you write `{ path: 'XXX', loadChildren: 'YYY' }` : **that doesn't define a route**. To define a route, you need to use `path` and `component`. But in your case, all path are empty in your 4 components, meaning all of the 4 routes are the same. This is what I meant by saying that ! Actually, `HomeComponent` have the same route as `LoginComponent` and the other 2 components (or you defined groups somewhere and didn't post it)

Comment: I think that that's not correct. When you define a Lazy Loading route like that you are specifying a Module to be loaded when the router matches the `path` key. You can see it here for example https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee

Comment: Well this was one of my issues for a couple of weeks, I actually had to make a bounty on SOF to get an answer to my question, hence my answer. But I will take a look if you don't think so, maybe I didn't understand it correctly !

Comment: Do you have a link to the question to give it a look? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, **[right there !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157010/angular-2-canload-usage)**

Comment: Oh well actually you're right, I totally inverted the answer :D my bad then ! I'll edit my answer